# Determine if first & last characters in a string are vowels and return true if they match

Tags: javascript

This function is continually returning false. Anything i'm missing here?

```
function regexVar() {
    var re = ""

    var last = re.length - 1
    var first = re[0]

    var match = (first === last) ? "true" : "false"

    if(match && (first == "a" ||
                first == 'e' ||
                first == 'i' ||
                first == 'o' ||
                first ==  'u')){
                console.log(true)
            } else {
                console.log(false)
            }
}
```

Comment: Am I not following something here? The empty string (your variable `re`) does not start and end with a vowel so I think this function is rightfully returning false.

Comment: setting `match` to a string - regardless of its content (as long as it's not an empty string) means `match` is truthy ... try making match a boolean .... i.e. match = first === last ... also, since re is en empty string, then it'll never start or end with a vowel anyway

Comment: `This function is continually returning false` in actual fact, this function doesn't return anything, it outputs false to console, which is not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You have set `first` to the first letter of the string but `last` is the index of the last letter, not the last letter itself. That means `first` will never `===` `last`. So match is always false.

Answer (score 0):

The `last = re.length - 1` equals `-1` cause `re.length` equals `0`

and `first = re[0]` is `undefined` because of empty string `re`

So your `match` is always `false` just like all the conditions below:

```
(first == "a" || first == 'e' || first == 'i' || first == 'o' || first ==  'u')
```